# Why does working in the own directory requires permission in Windows?

Tags: windows, terminal, permissions

So I'm working in the directory `C:\Users\terminator` that's me (`terminator` user), and I have a `workspace` folder inside `terminator` If I try to move files using a code editor I get the following error

[image: EPREM]

The error clearly states that I need an administrator's permission to carry out this operation, but this seems quite weird to me, why is this happening? Is this how Windows works? coming from a Linux background, I can do anything inside my `~` directory without requiring any superuser permission,

did I mess up something with my system? or this is how Windows works?

Doing the same operation from `bash` works fine,

[image: works fine in bash]

but doing anything with the `cmd` gives Access Denied immediately.

[image: cmd crying in the cornor]

I think my permissions are fine as well

[image: permissions]

Comment: “The error clearly states that I need an administrator's permission” - Actually it doesn’t, that’s not a Windows permission error, it’s a Visual Studio Code error.

Comment: I thought `EPREM` meant, I needed more privileges to run the operation. I think It has nothing to do with the Visual Studio code command prompt behaving the same way, I have edited the question please check this out, running in the administrator mode clears the problem, my permission seems quite fine to me, I have added that too, I have full access

Comment: Normally it does mean that, but even on Linux it is a distinct error from `EACCES` that means "file permissions don't allow this" – EPERM specifically means "something else *beyond* file permissions disallows this". Though in this case, I suspect it's just a bad choice of error code and the real cause might be the directory being "busy" (open).

Comment: Although not necessarily relevant, you are moving `src` into `articles` instead when in git bash.

Comment: Yes i probably slapped wrong, screenshot  here, but the other way works in bash

Comment: A file being in use can also give an Access Denied error.

Comment: You shouldn't mix file operations between Windows and MINGW on the same folders. Use one or the other only, or this can result in a mess.

Comment: @LPChip Indeed, but it's not in use in my case, I checked using `handle`

Comment: Logic suggests that it should work without admin, yet you still get an error. I'd check again if I were you. Maybe handle doesn't provide the correct information.